# How to open a new View from ListView

Tags: javascript, android, listview, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-alloy

I'm building an app with appcelerator studio. In my View I have insert a custom ListView with a "Templates". This is ok.

This is that I can see:
[image]

Now I want that if I click on one of this rows, I can open another View, width also some effect (of slider for e.g.).

This is my code of my xml file:

```
<Alloy>
    <View class="containerClinicalFolder" >

        <ListView id="elementsList" defaultItemTemplate="elementTemplate">
            <Templates>
                <ItemTemplate name="elementTemplate" class="itemTemplate">

                    <View id="atomProperties">
                        <Label bindId="name" id="name" />
                        <View id="secondLine">
                            <Label class="line2 fieldLabel" text="from: " />
                            <Label class="line2" bindId="dateStart" id="dateStart" />
                            <Label class="line2 fieldLabel" text=" to: " />
                            <Label class="line2" bindId="dateEnd" id="dateEnd" />
                        </View>
                        <Label bindId="quantity" id="quantity" left="0"/>
                    </View>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </Templates>
            <ListSection>               
                <ListItem quantity:text="10 minute" quantity:color="#090"  name:text="Hydrogen" dateStart:text="10-10-2016" dateEnd:text="10-12-2016"/>
                <ListItem quantity:text="15 minute" quantity:color="#090" name:text="Helium" dateStart:text="02-01-2015" dateEnd:text="10-10-2019"/>
                <ListItem quantity:text="25 minute" quantity:color="#090" name:text="Lithium" dateStart:text="01-01-2001" dateEnd:text="01-01-2018"/>
                <ListItem quantity:text="10 minute" quantity:color="#090"  name:text="Hydrogen" dateStart:text="10-10-2016" dateEnd:text="10-12-2016"/>

            </ListSection>
        </ListView> 


        <Button id="button" class="buttonLanguage" 
            visible="false" traduzione="true"></Button>

         <ImageView image="/images/add_circle_2.png" action="add" id="idImage" class="add"></ImageView>
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

So, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the onItemclick event to your listView(I left out your template for readability):

```
<ListView id="elementsList" onItemclick="listItemClick">
```

Now in your controller set this following function:

```
function listItemClick(e){ /* Open new window here. */ };
```

Tip: You can get information like the clicked row index from the event data(parameter e).